# `deployments.get` not allowing me to call functions

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a contract that is deployed when I run a `hardhat deploy`.

```js
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract SampleCode {
    uint256 public variable;

    constructor() public {
        variable = 5;
    }

    function getVariable() public view returns(uint256){
        return variable;
    }
}
```

And I deploy it with :

```js
deployments.deploy('SampleCode', {...})
```

But when I try to call my function, I am unable to:

```js
sampleCode = await deployments.get("SampleCode")
sampleCode.getVariable()
```

With:

```
Uncaught TypeError: sampleCode.getVariable is not a function
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

`await deployments.get("SampleCode")` doesn't return a specific instance of a contract by design.

You need to get the actual contract after you get the deployment:

```
SampleCode = await deployments.get("SampleCode")
sampleCode = await ethers.getContractAt("SampleCode", SampleCode.address)
sampleCode.getVariable()
```

Or, you can just do:

```
sampleCode = await ethers.getContractAt("SampleCode")
```

With the `hardhat-deploy-ethers` if you have that installed.